# Non-destructible read from a stream

Tags: c++, io, stream

Is is possible to try to read from a stream but do not change the stream itself (and return bool whether it was a success)?

```
template <typename T> bool SilentRead (stringstream& s, T& value) {
    stringstream tmp = s;
    tmp >> value;
    return tmp;
}
```

This doesn't work because stringstream doesn't have public copy constructor.
How to do it then?

Is it possible to solve it if we replace stringstream with istream ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StringStream, refering to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/) allows you to use [tellg](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/tellg/) and [seekg](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/seekg/) to get / set position. So you could:
 1. Get current position
 2. Read
 3. Set current position to one, that you have just read.

Comment: Of course :). I was refering strictly to std::stringstream (will work for streams on normal files as well).

Answer (score 2):

In general this is impossible. The underlying streambuf doesn't have an interface. However, you could create a streambuf wrapper. You still wouldn't be able to do non-destructible reads on the stream, but you could do them on your streambuf wrapper.

(A streambuf wrapper is an implementation of the std::streambuf interface which forwards its I/O to an underlying streambuf)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for Peek() - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/peek/

Comment: peek can lookahead only one char, doesn't it?